# Removing an XML Node with OpenCV

Tags: xml, opencv

How do I read an existing XML file with OpenCV, remove a node and write the file back?

When saving an SVM classifier model, the training creates two nodes in the XML: `<uncompressed_sv_total>` and `<uncompressed_support_vectors>` which dominate the file size and are *unused* by the prediction (at least for the `LINEAR` classfier).

I'd like to automatically remove these nodes so that my model file size is significantly reduced.

Comment: [FileStorage](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/dd/d74/tutorial_file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html) wasn't useful for this task?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it with FileStorage.

Comment: Hi did you figure out how to do this? I'm in the exact same situation.